# React-Select sub-components, how can you identify what the relevant sub-component is without shooting in the dark?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

What I mean is, there's [a list of the various sub-components](https://react-select.com/styles#style-object) of a `react-select` in the documentation, but it's not at all clear what some of these sub-components are. For example, `valueContainer`. There's no element in the DOM with anything resembling that string in the classnames.

Meanwhile there are other elements like the first child of the `Control` sub-component, which are not labeled at all in their class names like this [image]

---

**Edit:**

The goal of trying to target these components is to avoid crazy styles rules like the below. If you opt to swap out the component with your own, it's also important to know what each element is.

```js
  control: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      '> div': {
        padding: 'none !important',
      },
  })
```

Comment: Well, I guess it's common for UI libs since they are complex, and for users, they rarely need to use that sub-component which not affect the styles at all. Export the necessary API only is also a goal for the designer.

Comment: Take a step back you can still catch them with browser dev tools so it shouldn't be a big deal

Comment: @keikai I can catch what? This mystery element (and others) are relevant to styling and I have no idea how one would style them in the given API but for identifying what component they are and using the API React-Select provides.

Comment: Once you find a parent component that has appeared in the document. All the left thing you need to do is to write a [nesting selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting/) to give the style to the `dark element`.

Comment: @keikai are you familiar with React-Select? My question is about React-Select. General CSS answers are not applicable.

Comment: I used it in our prod env and have answered quite a lot about this lib. I didn't see any difficult handling the customized styles with `react-select`, although it does make some difference with `material-ui` and other `style-component` libs

Comment: Guessing this discussion is more suitable for an issue for them :). Inform me if you want them to disappear.

Comment: @keikai I've updated the issue to demonstrate the sort of pattern we're trying to find a way to avoid relying on.